# Reverse ToStringBuilder : convert string to object with nested object

Tags: java, apache

Is there a way to convert my output from `ToStringBuilder` back to java object?

Because of some reason,I need to convert some `String` to `object`, these string are converted from java object by `ToStringBuilder`.

like this:

```
[homeRequest=HomeRequest[homeDate=Tue Mar 10 07:58:17 CST 2015,homeInfo=[HomeInfo[ipId=<null>,name=Test]]]]
```

`HomeRequest` is a object and  `HomeInfo`  is a object.

Comment: Yes there is a way. Parse the string an create new instances of `HomeRequest` and ` HomeInfo`. What have you done so far?

Comment: You would need to create a custom String parser to pull out the needed information. For example, remove the first and last brackets, then remove "homeRequest=". Pull in the substring between the first index of '[' and the last index of ']' (this would be your HomeRequest object). Then use various substrings to pull in the rest of the information.

Comment: The question is whether the string representation includes *all* the state information in the original object. You'll need to add the definition of the class and the specific call to `ToStringBuilder` that was used to your question for this to be answered.

Comment: @SubOptimal I can parse a simple object string like HomeInfo[ipId=<null>,name=Test]]  ,but I don't know how to make it more  common

Comment: In general, no - there is no way to convert output from ToStringBuilder from certain objects into an exact clone of those objects: ToStringBuilder will not render circular refs in a way that allows them to be restored, for example. However, in certain cases, no information will be lost by the original conversion to string, and it may be possible to recover the original object. Show us source to see if your case is the general one or the lucky one.

Comment: @tucuxi What if I have the Class definition?

Comment: @bystander - I am assuming that you have the class definition; without it you would have had no chance. With it, it still depends on the source. If you have the .class and no .java, decompile it using jode or similar to get a source to post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to split the values.

```
String line = "[homeRequest=HomeRequest[homeDate=Tue Mar 10 07:58:17 CST 2015,homeInfo=[HomeInfo[ipId=<null>,name=Test]]]]";

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^.*HomeRequest\\[homeDate=([^,]*),.*HomeInfo\\[ipId=([^,]*),name=([^\\]]*).*");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    String homeDate = m.group(1);
    String ipId = m.group(2);
    String name = m.group(3);
    ...
    // create new instances of the objects
}
```

*explanation of the regex:*

`^.*HomeRequest\\[homeDate=` - match all characters from the beginning of the line till `homeDate=`

`([^,]*)`- match an unspecified amount of characters stop before the first `,`, this group can later be accessed by the group index 1

`,.*HomeInfo\\[ipId=` - matches from the `,` till the literal any character

`([^,]*)`- match an unspecified amount of characters stop before the first `,`, this group can later be accessed by the group index 2

`,name=` - matches the literal substring

`([^\\]]*)` - match an unspecified amount of characters stop before the first `]`, this group can later be accessed by the group index 3

`.*` - matches all following characters

For further explanation of the regular expression have a look here [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tW3sY6/1). There you will find and full explanation of above example.